# Empty select box on chromium / debian

Tags: debian, chromium

On chromium/ debian, sometimes, select boxes are empty, as you can see:

[image]

whereas, on another browser, iceweasel (eg firefox), the select box appears correctly.

[image]

Even on chromium, this problem is not permanent. 
Is it a known bug, and is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

As far as known bugs are concerned, take your pick :

[Issue 400837: Context and Drop-Down Menus Broken w/ HiDPI Enabled](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=400837)
Aug 5, 2014, to May 22, 2015
Apparently fixed with Chrome version 44.

[Issue 502268: drop-down select boxes empty](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=502268)
Jun 19, 2015, to Jul 30, 2015
Unsolved - the only workaround is to restart Chrome.

[Issue 510079: Select boxes empty](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510079)
Jul 14, 2015, to Jul 22, 2015
Unsolved.

[Issue 515451: drop-down select boxes empty](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=515451)
Jul 30, 2015, to Aug 3, 2015
Unsolved. Workaround: disabling hardware acceleration may fix the problem, then
hardware acceleration can be re-enabled.

The problem might also be related to using multiple monitors.
It is never permanent, but seems impossible to predict when it will happen.

Comment: I am using two monitors, I confirm that seems unpredictable. Sometimes I  just have to close the window and open a new one to recover a normal behavior, but sometimes, even if I kill all chromium processes, the bugs is still here after...